# Json encode php file

Tags: php, json, encode

I want to print Json data from a mysql database but the data are not shown correctly in the browser. I am entering names with accents, for example: José or L'Alcudia (they are Spanish names)
I have two php files, one to insert data into the database and another to return JSON data.
On the other hand, I have a html file (a form) that allows me to enter data.

```
//HTML FILE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<header></header>
<body>
<form id="formulario" name="formulario" method="post" action="insertar_persona.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <p>Nombre:</p>
    <input type="text" name="nombre" value="nombre" />      
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="submit" id="insertar" name="insertar" value="Insertar"/>

</form>
</body>
</html>



//INSERT PHP FILE

<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Credenciales de la BBDD
$db = "prueba";
$host = 'localhost';
$username = "dpbataller";
$password = '1234';

//Conectamos al servidor de la Base de datos
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("No se puede conectar");
//Seleccionamos la BBDD
@mysql_select_db($db) or die ("No se ha podido seleccionar a la base de datos");
//Lanzamos la consulta
$consulta = mysql_query("INSERT INTO personas (id,nombre) VALUES ('','$_POST[nombre]')");
?>



//GET JSON DATA
<?php header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
//Credenciales de la BBDD
$db = "prueba";
$host = 'localhost';
$username = "dpbataller";
$password = '1234';
//Conectamos al servidor de la Base de datos
$link = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die("No se puede conectar");
//Seleccionamos la BBDD
mysql_select_db($db) or die ("No se ha podido seleccionar a la base de datos");
//Lanzamos la consulta 
$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT id,nombre from personas");
//Creamos un array para almacenar los resultados
$filas = array();
//Agregamos las filas  devueltas al array
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($consulta)) { 
$filas[] = $r;  

}
//Devolvemos el resultado
echo json_encode($filas);
?>
```

When I try to display the data by the browser shows this:

```
[{"Id": "1", "name": "Jos \ u00e9"}]
```

The encoding of the database and table is utf-8_spanish_ci

What happens? Someone help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change content-type as: application/json

```
<?php header ('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: It does not work, it still appears

[{"id": "1", "name": "Jos \ u00e9"}, {"id": "2", "name": "asd"}]

Comment: I think it is raw of json string. Have you try decode the client side? look at jQuery.parseJSON

Answer (score 0):

You can use these functions:

```
function encodeIt($array) { 
  return json_encode(array_map('base64_encode', $array));
}

function decodeIt($string) {
  return array_map('base64_decode', json_decode($string));
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to php programming and do not quite understand where I put the functions and what are the parameters that I pass.

Comment: Include these functions in the top section of your script and use them in place of json_encode and json_decode respectively.